# ¿Como descargar archivos sin importar el S.O., desde un sitio FTP a través de asp.net y VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ftp

tengo un sitio FTP, y un sitio asp.net, donde quiero poder descargar archivos desde el FTP. Hay 2 escenarios.

1.- Tener acceso a un HTML que sirve de plantilla para rellenarlo y mostrarlo en pantalla.

2.- Descargar archivos como PDF y cosas así.

La cuestión es que puedo hacerlo si hablamos de PC, pero si la página se ve en Android o en iOs? ¿Como puedo programar una acción de descarga que vaya a descargas del S.O.?

Comment: Se ve en Android como app o como página? Cómo está implementado? Qué problema tienes? Cuál es la pregunta puntual?

Comment: Es una página básica asp.net con una plantilla administrativa. A veces se requieren descargar archivos que tengo en el FTP como facturas, etc. La cuestión es que en winforms, buscaba el path de descargas de windows y listo, pero en la página depende desde que SO se abre. Mi pregunta es si hay algun método que apunte a la crpeta de descargas sin importar el SO.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario forzar la carpeta de descarga. Los SO van a guardar las descargas en forma predeterminada en la carpeta que tengan configurada como de "descargas" o "downloads"